# Inserting , updating and deleting of Data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make a control that show list of bounded data like in grid view but I want to be able to insert new record from the same control

what is the best asp.net control I can use to do that (GridView , FormView or DetailsView)? and why?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with all three.  If you want to know how, there are some good tutorials on the official ASP.NET website, [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/data).

The choice between them is a formatting/layout decision.  A GridView produces a table, showing multiple records, while a DetailsView shows one at a time.  A FormView lets you display the data however you want, but required much more effort, since you have to provide the HTML.